# Java HttpsURLConnection reuse

Tags: java, php

**What am I trying to achieve:**

I have a piece of Java code that's meant to connect to a web server in HTTPS. I want to use JVM's built-in HttpsURLConnection only. The intention is to keep the http connection open for an authenticated user and keep sending and receiving GET/POST requests. Once authenticated, all GET/POST requests will have the same PHP session ID I received from piece of php code at the web server. That PHP is actually the one that takes in the requests from my java app, processes (DB handling) and outputs in XML to my client for my better data handling.

**The Problem:**

I need to keep the same HttpsURLConnection open for the URL (since all requests are going to the same documentroot) and keep changing the parameters in the GET as I move along the client application. But as HTTP is intended to serve only one request at a time, I do not get to resend data without reinitializing the HttpsURLConnection. In that case, my session ID gets changed (because of obvious reasons of new HTTP connection) and I end up nowhere. Below is the piece of code I crafted out of my main app to clarify what I did (please disregard braces close):

```
    try{
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/?type=login&username=testu&password=testp");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)(url).openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println("Response: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("" + in.readLine());

        url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/?type=login&username=testu1&password=testp1");
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connecting..." + conn.getRequestMethod());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Response: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("" + in.readLine());
        System.out.println("" + conn.getHeaderFields());

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

**Sample output from above code:**

Connecting...
Response: 200
fipfk4pq0ov68bssicug3pv0d3testu
Connecting...POST
Response: 200
hqe9j1kmbdc98f5q1g2vkepb11testu1

**Query:**

Is it possible to keep my HttpsURLConnection still pointing to the same URL, while I change the GET request parameters?

Comment: Have a seperate method to do the request. Pass your url to that method as a parameter

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the response, but the code I pasted is an example of how I am trying to address my requirement. I am passing the GET strings in my real app, but it didn't work out.

Comment: I would welcome any suggestions. I am still stuck on this deployment